# How to define a template class variable inside of another class?

Tags: c++, class

I defined a template class first, then defined another class Node_3, and in that class I defined a variable that its type is class first called Tree_2. Now this worked fine, but when I try to write a function getTree_2 which is supposed to return the Tree_2 class I get an error, I can't understand why...
The error I get:

> - Invalid arguments ' Candidates are: first < second::Node_2,second::Cmp_node2> *
>     Tree_2(second::Cmp_node2) '

Something like this:

```
template <class element, class compare_fuc>
class first {
   int x;
   compare_fuc cmpFunc;
   // more things here
   public:
         first(compare_fuc cmp): x(0),cmpFunc(cmp) {};
         ~first() {};

         // and more things here
   };
```

Now I defined another class that is supposed to define a variable from class first type:

```
class second{

private:

class Node_2{
    int y1;
    int y2;
    public:

    explicit Node_2(int y1,int y2) : y1(y1),y2(y2){};

    ~Node_2() {};
};

class Node_3{
private:
//Cmp_node2 is a class i defined that compares nodes 2
first<Node_2,Cmp_node2>* Tree_2(Cmp_node2);
puclic:
    first<Node_2,Cmp_node2>* getTree_2()
    {
        return Tree_2;  /// here i get the error
    }
};
};
```

Comment: How can you misspell "defined" in four different ways... By the way, `Tree_2` is a function, not a variable.

Comment: english is a difficult language :(

Comment: `return Tree_2(Cmp_node2{});` ?

Comment: i got this error when i did what you suggested : extended initializer lists only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11

Comment: `return Tree_2(Cmp_node2());` in `C++03`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, first, you haven't provided a definition of `Cmp_node2`; and you have some typos. But when we [fix your code](https://godbolt.org/g/7Bdwi2), we see that the problem is that you've mis-defined `Type2`, that's all:

```
<source>: In member function 'first<second::Node_2, second::Cmp_node2>* 
second::Node_3::getTree_2()':

<source>:40:20: error: cannot convert 'second::Node_3::Tree_2' 
from type 'first<second::Node_2, second::Cmp_node2>*(second::Node_3::)(second::Cmp_node2)' 
to type 'first<second::Node_2, second::Cmp_node2>*'
```

Why do you get this? Well, look at the definition:

```
first<Node_2,Cmp_node2>* Tree_2(Cmp_node2);
```

You thought you were defining a member *variable* of type `first<whatever>*`, but actually, you defined a member *function* which takes a `Cmp_node2` and returns a `first<whatever>*` !

Comment: basicly all i am trying is : first is supposed to be at the end an avl tree .. and Node_3 is a templete kind for the avl tree , but in this node i want it to point to another avl tree from another kind which is Node_2 .. and this is what i did but in a larger code but this sums up exactly my problem

Comment: @jena90: I am not making any suggestions about whether your classes and their functionality makes sense. I'm just saying that you've gotten the syntax wrong.

Comment: but someone above helped me and it fixed everything :\

Comment: @jena90: Once you ask a question here, it's no longer about whether you managed to fix everything, it's about other people reading the question and the answer.

Comment: but i honestly thought i wrote a good question , i am sorry and i will keep this in mind

Comment: @jena90: Once you clarifies what you didn't understand, it became a better question... if you edit your question to have the complete code which just gives out the single compiler error, I'll undo my downvote :-)